# Manipulate MPI to think I am running on two nodes

Tags: fortran, mpi, hpc

I am developing an application which needs to take some
Other actions when running on two nodes. 
As my own computer is obviously considered as node, I was wondering if I could manipulate MPI to believe I am running on two nodes with e.g two cores each. This makes things a bit easier for me to test and debug my application on my own computer before testing on a cluster.

I am using Intel MPI on Linux machine

Comment: Does your app use `MPI_Comm_split_type()`? If not, how does it currently figure out it is running on two distinct nodes?

Comment: depending on the MPI distribution you are using (eg: MPICH, OpenMPI,...) the syntax is different, but the concept is: configure a hostfile where you specify that "localhost has 2 slots". You will fill your hostfile with "localhost". Which distribution? are we speaking of a linux host, isn't it?

Comment: I am using this Yes and using MPI_COMM_TYPE_SHARED as the type split. I am running on Linux and using Intel’s distribution.

Comment: In this case, I would simply rewrite `MPI_Comm_split_type()` to return two communicators and trick your app into believing it runs on two nodes.

Comment: I agree with Gilles - but would probably do it as a wrapper for the splitting routine that then does the appropriate thing dependent on the hardware platform

Comment: or you can implement `MPI_Comm_split_type()` in a shared library and only `LD_PRELOAD` it when running on your laptop.

Answer (score -1):

The "nodes" in MPI (usually referred to as "ranks") do not have to match physical compute nodes. In fact, it can even be beneficial to run multiple MPI processes ("ranks") per physical node. The [HPC Tuning Guide for AMD EPYC](http://developer.amd.com/wp-content/resources/56420.pdf) gives some guidelines for their CPUs as an example, Intel MPI uses the `-ppn` option to [configure number of processes per node](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mpi-developer-guide-linux-controlling-process-placement).

That being said: if you simply need to run your application on two MPI ranks on your host, then it is usually as easy as running

```
$ mpirun -n 2 your-app.x
```

to get two ranks on your local machine (since most MPI implementations pre-configure slots equal to the number of physical CPUs on your host). Whether or not they are local does not matter for you, the MPI implementation will choose the appropriate way of communication for the two processes.

In case `mpirun` explicitly needs a host, use:

```
$ mpirun -host localhost -n 2 your-app.x
```

With additional options for `mpirun` (consult the reference documentation) you can even pin the MPI processes to specific CPUs, although the MPI implementation and the OS usually distribute them well enough for test runs.

If you really need to have `mpirun` handle your single host as two nodes, you can use the fact that on Linux the complete `127.0.0.x` subnet maps to your localhost and combine the `-host` and `-ppn` options. With the default MPI helloworld program this looks like:

```
$ FI_PROVIDER=tcp mpiexec -ppn 2 -hosts 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2 ./helloworld
Hello world from processor myhost, rank 1 out of 4 processors
Hello world from processor myhost, rank 3 out of 4 processors
Hello world from processor myhost, rank 0 out of 4 processors
Hello world from processor myhost, rank 2 out of 4 processors
```

The internal hostname resolution unfortunately gives you always the same processor name, but the fact that you get 4 ranks while requesting for 2 processors per node shows that this works as requested.

The `FI_PROVIDER` I had to specify to workaround an [issue in the latest Intel MPI](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-clusters-and-hpc-technology/topic/799716).

Btw, this is not Fortran specific.

Comment: But I am not asking for how to run mpi on a linux.  I am asking how to manipulate MPI to "think" that e.g. ranks 1 to 4 are associated to node 1 and ranks 5-8 to node 2, for example.
I think @Gilles Gouaillardet last comment is the best way to do it

Comment: I don't see why you would want to have code which depends on whether you actually have two different nodes, rather than just two ranks, since that's what an HPC cluster should be able to abstract away. But nevertheless, I've updated the answer with an example showing that you can indeed treat your local node as multiple ones.